# Can someone else dominate my own thrall?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

The situation is this, I am playing two characters back and forth. One is the Sire and the other, the Childe. The Childe is level 3 bonded to her Sire. I recognise I can dominate my own thrall. My question is, can *someone else* dominate my Childe? Like, perhaps a frienemy in our Coterie.

I'd keeping reading and digging for an answer but I'm tired of staring at a screen. I hope you guys can help.

Comment: Hi Beany! Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange. I see from your Informed badge that you've already read our [tour], thanks for doing that. When you reach 20 rep, you'll also be able to join us in [chat].

Answer (score 7):

## Yes, usually

The Dominate Discipline (*Vampire the Masquerade*, 2000 printing, p 156-160) can cause the target vampire to perform actions that the Dominator desires (Command, Mesmerize), alter or destroy the victim's memories (The Forgetful Mind), or take over her will entirely (Conditioning). Only a Dominator with a blood bond to the victim can Possess another Kindred. The sidebar about resisting Dominate (158) says:

> Most victims cannot stand against the effects of Dominate...

Only being lower generation than the Dominator prevents Domination completely. Nature (which *might* be akin to a blood bond) can influence the target's susceptibility to Domination, but doesn't prevent its function inherently.

Now, p218-220 has this to say about the Blood Bond and Dominate (emphasis mine):

> ...Even the most potent uses of Dominate cannot overcome *the thrall's feelings for her regnant*...[at the third drink] the drinker is more or less completely bound to the vampire. He is the most important person in her life...a regnant may use the Dominate Discipline on a thrall, even without the use of eye contact...

So Dominate cannot break a Blood Bond, and *perhaps* cannot cause the Dominated vampire thrall to act directly against her regnant or his *known* wishes; the regnant is the first thing on her mind, always. That would appear to be the only limitations imposed by a blood bond on Dominate. These limits are *not* spelled out and so are up to the Storyteller to decide; she may decide that the Kindred can be Conditioned to follow the Dominator, for example, or not.

The paragraph in the third drink blood bond description starting

> A full blood bond, once formed, is nearly inviolate...

is talking about being bound to more than one vampire, not Domination. It's not possible to be bound at the third drink level to more than one regnant; an existing full-bond must "wear away 'naturally'" before beginning another blood bond.